# document.dispatchEvent in contentscript.js does not invoke handlers attached to DOM elements

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

**High Level Problem**

There is no deselect all for 'Other Calendars' in google calendars. We have many employees at my company and I'm constantly adding and removing users when scheduling meetings. I realize there's a 'Find time' feature but aside from that argument I'd like to get this working because I find it interesting.

[image: Screenshot of some Other Calendars]

**Solution**

Create a page action chrome extension which appears when a tab is on the Google Calendar site. Clicking the page action icon should automate deselecting all calendars by simulating mousedown events.

**Implementation**

Page action functions correctly with the exception of actually deselecting the calendars.

I used Google Developer tools to see which events fire when I deselect manually and also to see which elements register a handler. The key pair seems to be the `document` element and the `mousedown` event. As such I wanted to automate dispatching an event to duplicate the behavior. I did at first dispatch directly on the div assuming it would bubble but when it didn't work and I saw the only event listeners were on the document I tried to raise the event directly there.

In `contentscript.js` the following method executes when the page action is clicked:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    // Get the div containing other calendars
    var otherCalendars = document.getElementById("calendars_fav");
    // Get all divs representing a single selected calendar
    var selectedOtherCalendars = otherCalendars.getElementsByClassName("calListLabel-sel");
    for (var i=0 ; i < selectedOtherCalendars.length; i++) {
            // Get the span which contains the name of the calendar e.g. Contact's birthdays
        var c = selectedOtherCalendars[i].children[1];
        var name = c.innerHTML;
            // Find the location of this element relative to the document
        var x = getOffsetLeft(c) + (c.offsetWidth / 2);
        var y = getOffsetTop(c) + (c.offsetHeight / 2);
        console.log('mousedown on document targeting ' + name + ' x:' + x + ', y:' + y);
            // See http://goo.gl/WtlWpv
        simulate(document, "mousedown", { pointerX: x, pointerY: y });
    }
});
```

[SO: How to simulate mouse click using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-using-javascript) - I lifted the simulate implementation from here

**Issue**

Logs seem correct and there are no errors but nothing happens and the simulation seems to fail.

- No event appears in the Chrome Developer Tools timeline when I dispatch the event programmatically
- No Google Calendar javascript is executed as a result of the dispatch

Sample log entry:

```
mousedown on body targeting  Ipswich Town x:85.5, y:494
```

**Title Clarification**

I don't know if dispatchEvent will work on google calendar from elsewhere I have only tried from my chrome extension `contentscript.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript you are adding is isolated from the web page's JavaScript. Try adding a script that bridges this isolation by putting a script element into the HTML with your JavaScript instead of trying to get JavaScript from the contentscript context to communicate with the web page context.

See: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication

Comment: Additional resources I needed to piece it together http://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/13696976/111734