# Detecting installed chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to detect chrome extensions, but I have a problem. When I try to `jQuery.load()` something like
`chrome-extension://jffbcpkfdlpegbadfomimojhgaaoaeed/icon.png` or some other file, I get this error:

```
Denying load of chrome-extension://jffbcpkfdlpegbadfomimojhgaaoaeed/icon.png. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension. movie.php?id=3079:1
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

Can I avoid web_accessible_resources? I tried to change the capitalization of the filename from something like icon.png to ICON.png without success ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696906/resources-must-be-listed-in-the-web-accessible-resources-manifest-key-in-order-t)).

The idea is ONLY to detect extension; nothing else.

I want to do something like [this](http://www.willhawker.com/what-i-learnt-today/20-11-2012/27).

Comment: I don't understand why i have -2? I just ask what i don't know to do and what problem i have?

Comment: Could you post more of your example?  You've given us nothing to work with.

Comment: Nathing special follow [THIS link](http://www.willhawker.com/what-i-learnt-today/20-11-2012/27)

Comment: This is using a different extension id.  Please post your complete extension.

Comment: Yes i need to detect more then one extension.

Comment: So you're trying to detect if an extension you don't control has been installed, and it doesn't have any web_accessible_resources?  Which extension(s) are you trying to detect?

Comment: Exactly. Easy Video Downloader Express,FVD Downloader,MoviePile Downloader,Video Downloader professional... and more.

Comment: Of your examples, #3 doesn't exist, and #2 and #4 have `web_accessible_resources`.  #1 lists the manifest entry, but no files match the wildcard.  I'd recommend focusing on #1.  But now I don't know enough to help you out.

Comment: I need detect all, with or without web_accessible_resources. If some extension have web_accessible_resources i just need to open that file (like alexa traffic rank) and i can detect but i have problem where i don't have web_accessible_resources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check whether user has a Chrome extension installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to detect that an extension is installed, for any given extension, you should not rely on hacks like loading web-accessible resources (which do not work uniformly for all extensions) and use [`chrome.management` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#type-ExtensionInfo) which is specifically there for this purpose.

```
chrome.management.get('keyoftheextensionyouwanttofind', function(info){
  if (!info) { console.log("Extension not installed"); }
  else if (!info.enabled) { console.log("Extension installed, but disabled"); }
  else {console.log("Extension installed and active");}
});
```

Yes, it will [trigger a permission warning](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings).

Comment: i don't want to create extension and i don't have extension, this is PHP page not extension

Comment: Well, this is not clear from your question. Sorry. I don't think you can do it, then, for extensions you don't control.