# How can I contain the styles of a Chrome Extension content script?

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, material-design-lite

I'm working on a Chrome extension that injects some UI react components into a page.

The UI components [come from `react-mdl`](https://github.com/react-mdl/react-mdl). Using them requires me to include a [css file](https://github.com/react-mdl/react-mdl/blob/master/extra/material.css) in the top of my project.

Unfortunately, once the `css` is injected into the page, the entire page's font is changed.

Is there a way to limit the scope of the `css` used by `react-mdl` such that it doesn't affect the page into which I'm injecting?

Comment: so this only happens with other webpages that use react?

Comment: No, I only inject into pages in one domain, and none of its pages use React (or any framework at all--just vanilla JS/jquery and css/html)

Comment: ok, can you share some of the css file? maybe just use custom class names that you know won't be used anywhere else

Comment: actually, I see the issue. the css file you linked has very generic tags like `body`. you may need to manually rename these

Comment: ah i was afraid of that. no way as far as you know to forceably scope it?  I can gut the `material.css` a little and get rid of the page-level stuff, but if i can avoid tampering with it, i'd love it.

Comment: sounds like if you gut it you should be ok. let me know if it works :)

Comment: messy work, this web design. thanks @NoamHacker. I may expermient with [this a bit first](https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss)

Comment: @NoamHacker turns out the `shadowDOM` mentioned by @Deliaz below works great. It encapsulates the styles i need entirely within my injected div.

Comment: thanks, glad I got to learn something new!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use the Shadow DOM API. It is good practice for those cases when you just need to append your UI component to a webpage.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom

Comment: thanks. i am going to have to fiddle a little with my webpack config to make the css inlining work correctly, but when I paste the entire `material.css` into a `style` tag in a `shadow` root, this works great.

Answer (score 7):

Just posting this for posterity as accepted answer deserves credit, but if anyone finds themselves in a similar predicament, here is a snippet of the code that worked for me:

```
// my injected code
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const injectDiv = document.createElement('div')
    const shadowRoot = injectDiv.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })

    // note inline use of webpack raw-loader, so that the css
    // file gets inserted as raw text, instead of attached to <head>
    // as with the webpack style-loader

    shadowRoot.innerHTML = // just using template string
      `
       <style>${require('raw-loader!app/styles/extension-material.css')}</style>
       <div id='shadowReactRoot' />
       `
    document.body.appendChild(injectDiv)
    ReactDOM.render(
          <App />,
          // note you have to start your query in the shadow DOM
          // in order to find your root
          shadowRoot.querySelector('#shadowReactRoot')
        )
})
```

Then, sure enough:

[image: shadow DOM inside the document]

Comment: For anyone trying to find a solution, since webpack 5, raw loader is not mandatory anymore, you should use asset/source

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176330/use-a-remote-stylesheet-inside-a-template-tag-with-shadow-dom), `<link>` tag is also supported, so one can simply do as follows:

```
const injectedDiv = document.createElement('div');
const shadowRoot = injectedDiv.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
shadowRoot.innerHTML = `\
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${chrome.runtime.getURL("bootstrap.min.css")}"></link>\
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${chrome.runtime.getURL("whatever.css")}"></link>\
`;
document.body.appendChild(injectedDiv);
```

Notes:

1. Using `chrome.runtime.getURL` is required for getting an extension's local resource url, see e.g. [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3560038/3002584).

   - The linked answer uses `chrome.extenstion.getURL`, which is deprecated since Chrome 58, and won't work in manifest V3 (see this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/extension/#method-getURL)).
2. The linked `.css` resources must be declared under the `web_accessible_resources` property in your `manifest.json` (otherwise, you'll get [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696906/resources-must-be-listed-in-the-web-accessible-resources-manifest-key-in-order-t))

Comment: `chrome.runtime.getURL` — the new API

Answer (score 0):

There're safer ways to import CSS instead of using link. Here's what I would do.

```
  const response = await fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL('your/path.css'))
  const cssText = await response.text();
  document.createElement('style').textContent = cssText;
```